# webkit animation works in chrome but not firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, transform, css-animations

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dgy2Q/3/

```
#LeftDoor{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width:50%;
z-index: 30;
background-color: blue; 
left:0px;
 -webkit-animation: leftDoorOpen 1s ease 1s; 
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: leftDoorOpen 4s ease 4s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftDoorOpen {
    from {
       -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
       -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(90deg);
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes leftDoorOpen {
   from {
   -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
to {
   -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(90deg);
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
 }
```

that works great in chrome.  It doesn't work in firefox, I can't see what I am doing wrong???  Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

thanks

have amended the fiddle but still no joy?  anything else?

http://jsfiddle.net/Dgy2Q/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in the `perspective` function. Its parameter should be a length, with a unit. Change the `300` to `300px` and it will work in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Dgy2Q/6/

The result is not identical though. Not sure what causes that, if it can be corrected with CSS or if it's simply different implementations in the browsers.